# Can't access CSS -files

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

Having some problems to access my css script.
Settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    '/C:/NetMagProjekt/netmag/netmag/static',
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)
```

Template base

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{STATIC_URL}}style.css"/>
```

If I look in source code in browser it looks like this:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{STATIC_URL}}style.css"/>
```

I can't find the css style.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure your url is right?

Comment: remove the leading `/`

Answer (score 2):

1. Remove the leading backsplach before `C:`
2. change `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{STATIC_URL}}style.css"/>` to `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/style.css"/>`

If these do not help, then try:

1. Make sure that `settings.py` contains the follows:

```python
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
  'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
  'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```

1. Make sure that `urls.py` contains the follows:

```python
# redirects to static media files (css, javascript, images, etc.)
(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 
   'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': 'static/'}),
```

Answer (score 1):

first you have to fix your code:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    'C:/NetMagProjekt/netmag/netmag/static',
)
```

also try one more thing, instead of using the static dir option use,

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'C:/NetMagProjekt/netmag/netmag/static'
```

try both options.

Answer (score 0):

Try collectstatic django command.

For Example :

```
cd project_dir
python manage.py collectstatic
```

For more details please refer [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django-admin-collectstatic)

put this line you root urls.py file.

```
# redirects to static media files (css, javascript, images, etc.)
(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 
   'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': 'static/'}),
```

Answer (score 0):

I would get the base path programmatically to avoid problems.

This is how it is setup in my project.

```
import os

BASE = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__name__))

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE, "<your dir name>"),
)
```

I would recommend you use the `python console` (started with python command in your terminal (probably, i'm not on windows) and then just running and printing the commands to see.

example:

```
$>python
>>> BASE = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__name__))
>>> BASE
'/string/to/directory/I/am/in/currently'
```

So that will return the absolute path to your settings file. and then you just join that path to where your static files are and you should be golden.

Answer (score -1):

Several things might be causing it.

Is STATIC_ROOT defined?

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'C:/NetMagProjekt/netmag/netmag/static'
```

Naturally, mAke sure the path is correct and get rid of the extra backslash before c:

In your template, make sure you have

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```

Even if extending a template that loads static files, I believe you need to add this again. and then possibly for the src url, this might help:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "style.css" %}">
```

and finally, load your static files:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```